# Is the quantifier modifying the verb or the noun in this sentence "He gave a lot of advice"?

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to find out if the quantifier is modifying the noun.

Comment: And what has your research shown you so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *He gave* [*a lot of advice*].

No: the non-count quantificational noun "lot" is not a modifier, but head of the NP "a lot of advice" functioning as direct object of "gave".

The PP "of advice" is complement of "lot".

Comment: Prezackerly so. (Stiiilll no news?)

Answer (score -3):

The "of" makes it a modifier of the noun.  Interestingly, you'd use a different word order to modify the verb, putting "a lot" actually further off:

> He gave advice a lot.

Note that "give advice" is here used as activity without any amount of advice specified.  You can make it specific as in

> He gave this advice a lot.

which still makes "a lot" modify the verb.  Once the advice is specific rather than a part of "give advice", you can juggle the sentence order into

> This advice he gave a lot.

to put emphasis on the particular advice, getting "a lot" closer to the verb again.

Comment: Eh? In the OP's example "lot" is a head, not a modifier.